# unable to retrieve layer detail using dxfgrabber

Tags: python, cad, dxf

In my Python script, I am reading dxf file using dxfgrabber and able to get layer's name and other information. One of my layer has text information in it and I am not able to get that text information via my code. So far I have tried below -

```
import dxfgrabber
dxf = dxfgrabber.readfile("/home/user/skype_files/289253.dxf")
myTextLayer = dxf.layers.__getitem__('Text-Info-Layer')
print myTextLayer.name, myTextLayer.linetype
```

Text-Info-Layer is the layer which contains text information but I have no idea how to get that. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

dxf.layers contains only the layer definitions. Collect all dxf entities of a specific layer by using a filter over dxf.entities, which contains all entities of the model space:

```
entities = [e for e in dxf.entities if e.layer=='Text-Info-Layer']
# collect all TEXT entities from layer 'Text-Info-Layer'
text_entities = [e for e in entities if e.dxftype=='TEXT']
# the attribute 'text' of the text entity contains the text
```